# Specs for a powered tailgate strut

Tags: struts

I'm looking for info on tailgate struts that are electric / hydraulic hybrids -- they accept a DC voltage from a control module to open, then close when +/- are flipped, with the action mediated by internal hydraulics. There are built-in sensors to (I presume) detect limits and pinches.

The one I'm dealing with is used by Land Rover, but I assume the notion is not unique to them.

This is not for a repair, but for a demo buck. I don't have access to the control module and need to mimic its behavior. The connections named are `power +, power -, Hall power, Hall ground, Hall sensors 1 and 2`, but no other data is available, including pinouts.

***Any*** information would be welcome -- manufacturers, sources, specs, internals, etc. The wide wonderful web doesn't seem to have any info, or I just don't know what search terms to use.

Comment: Please note that I'm not looking for a solution to a specific problem, I'm looking for information about the sort of strut that operates this way. I don't have any data other than what I posted. I don't know the manufacturer, or the model of the strut in question. But it doesn't matter because what I need are leads to ***any*** similar strut or strut maker so I can investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

most likely the hall sensor is what is determining if the tailgate is closed or open. Most powered struts will not have enough power to close a truck tailgate.

I suspect:

- power+ is going to be positive going to the struts hydraulic pump
- power- is going back to ground
- hall power is positive power to the hall sensor
- hall ground is self explanatory
- hall sensors 1 and 2 are most likely for positioning (stopping positions).

the first thing you need to do is figure out how much force is required to fully close your tailgate. once you get that then it is find a system that will work.

What is your ultimate goal? Why make an automatic truck tailgate? have you thought of a reel, motor, and cable?

---

- what equipment / parts do you currently have?
- what land rover are you working with?
- what equipment is missing from the land rover?
- when you stated you have named connections but need the pinouts I am assuming you have the part but not the control module so please rephrase this.
- basically your question needs to be more concise with more information as I am a computer tech not a mind reader.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What you've speculated about the connections and sensors is fairly obvious. But I have no pinouts, and no combination of connections so far has provided any sensor output. That's why I need manufacturer info.  I can drive the piston in either direction with a fairly low voltage, it's not one-directional. This isn't a truck tailgate, but a powered minivan lift gate. I have no choice in the platform or mechanism -- it's on a buck that already has the strut installed.

Comment: ok that is where I was getting confused. you said tailgate then buck so I thought it was a typo for truck. What is a buck? I would need a part to be able to look up the pinouts for that part. I am not even sure of which vehicle you are trying to get the rams off of.

Comment: Sorry, trade talk. A buck is a mockup or cutaway of a section of a vehicle (such as an isolated instrument panel) designed to show its construction or demonstrate its use. This is the rear section of a Land Rover SUV. If I had a part number or really any identification I could discover the mfr and go from there, but I don't and that's why I'm asking more general questions here.

Comment: @JimMack aha might I suggest rewording the questions then. take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know how I could be more clear. I'm looking for any information -- not speculation -- about this type of strut. Like, who makes them, how do they work internally, etc. You know what I know if you read the original question. If you don't know anything about such items then I'm happy to wait for an answer from someone who does.

Comment: @JimMack well primarily I need to know some of the stuff I added to my answer like what equipment do you have what are you specifically looking for. I will edit your question with clarification questions take a look at it.